# How to wait until io.mockk captured slots will be filled while calling a method that contains asynchronous operations? (Unit Test)

Tags: unit-testing, testing, kotlin, mockk

PS: Codes in Kotlin

In my unit test,

I have mutable list of string called slot

```
val slot = mutableListOf<String>()
```

I captured this slot list

```
every { someService.whateverMethod(capture(slot)) } just Runs
```

In the end of certain test I check size of slot.

```
slot.size shouldBe 2
```

A method that I test contains asynchronous operations. Accordingly, I should write `Thread.sleep(1000)` before checking slot size (`slot.size shouldBe 2`)

How to refuse `Thread.sleep(1000)` operation, and make something that will wait for 1 second. Something like `verify(timeout = 10000)`.

Comment: `verify` has a `timeout` parameter. Check out the function parameter list that `verify` accepts.

Comment: @RamanPreetSingh I do not mean exactly `verify` method. Something that does almost the same logic.

Comment: I think you need `import io.mockk.slot` and `val slotList = slot<MutableList<String>>()`,  `every { someService.whateverMethod(capture(slotList)) } just Runs`